# pthread: destroying global static mutex

Tags: c, pthreads, reentrancy

This code was taken from the 3rd edition of Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment, written by Richard Stevens. This is an example of how to make a reentrant version of `getenv()`. It is demostrated here only for a learning purpose.

```
/* Copyright (c) W.R.Stevens */
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern char **environ;

pthread_mutex_t env_mutex;

static pthread_once_t init_done = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;

static void
thread_init(void)
{
    pthread_mutexattr_t attr;

    pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE);
    pthread_mutex_init(&env_mutex, &attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr);
}

int
getenv_r(const char *name, char *buf, int buflen)
{
    int i, len, olen;

    pthread_once(&init_done, thread_init);
    len = strlen(name);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&env_mutex);
    for (i = 0; environ[i] != NULL; i++) {
        if ((strncmp(name, environ[i], len) == 0) &&
          (environ[i][len] == '=')) {
            olen = strlen(&environ[i][len+1]);
            if (olen >= buflen) {
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&env_mutex);
                return(ENOSPC);
            }
            strcpy(buf, &environ[i][len+1]);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&env_mutex);
            return(0);
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&env_mutex);
    return(ENOENT);
}
```

This code is easy to understand. I have a question though. We're never calling `pthread_mutex_destroy()`, which means that there may be a memory leak on exit (I guess it may differ between platforms).

First thing that comes to mind is that one may use `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`. Does it require `pthread_mutex_init()` call? If no, there is no need to call `pthread_mutex_destroy()`. However, the mutex will be non-recursive.

One could write a simple C++ class that could destroy mutex in destructor. However, it is not suitable for anyone who has only C compiler (and it seems to be a bullshit to use C++ compiler because of one function).

The other thing that comes to mind are compiler-specific extensions like `__attribute__((destructor))` in GCC (and hopefully clang). However, it is non-portable.

Is it possible to avoid a memory leak? If yes, how can that be done in C?

**UPDATE**
As appears in "Programming with POSIX threads" written by David Butenhof, we never need to destroy `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` variant. How about mutexes with other attributes?

Answer (score 5):

Resources that are still live at process termination are not memory leaks, despite some naive tools classifying them as such. A memory leak is an irreversible and unbounded growth of a program's resource requirements during its lifetime that's disproportionate to the actual working set.

Per POSIX (which is where you get POSIX threads), all process-local resources cease to exist at program termination. There is no need to destroy/free them explicitly, and in some cases, like yours, you *cannot safely destroy/free them* and you *should not try to*.

Comment: +1 excellent answer. Makes a change from the cargo-cult 'you must always explicitly destroy all resources before terminating your process', (even if this is difficult/dangerous and requires a load of extra code and testing).

Answer (score 1):

No memory leak because `pthread_mutex_t` variables live in user memory, on process exit all user allocated memory is reclaimed. Memory leaks occur when something allocates heap memory, like strdup.
And then you do not clean it up.

If it were allocated like

```
pthread_mutex_t *foo;
....
foo =malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t);
```

And then not released with free that creates a memory leak -- if then foo got allocated to more new memory. However at process termination ALL memory the process requested including heap is reclaimed by the OS.  Stevens explains this in the chapter on processes.  That code does not leak.

Comment: I was thinking about allocations during `pthread_mutex_init()`. If there exist both `init()` and `destroy()`, should we care about calling them both?

Comment: You don't really need to call them both if your mutex lasts as long as your entire program does. But imagine you were creating, say, a linked list that had a mutex in it, and you used that list only for one function, then `free()`d it. *Then* you'd want to make sure you called `pthread_mutex_destroy()`, otherwise if you call that function many times during the course of your program those leaks are going to add up.